# How to stop VS 2015 from beautifying web.config?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-config, code-formatting

Since I upgraded to VS 2015 I noticed that it keeps beautifying my web.config files, maybe on each build. But I want some of the tags to be formatted differently than the beautiy rules, so it's pretty annoying.

For example, I want this:

```
<add
    name="EcoMembershipProvider"
    type="Eco.Web.AspProviders.EcoMembershipProvider"
    EcoSpaceTypeName="Diamonds.DiamondsEcoSpace"
    enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
    enablePasswordReset="true"
    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
    requiresUniqueEmail="true"
    passwordFormat="Hashed"
    userNameCaseSensitive="false"
    applicationName="/Diamonds" />
```

rather than this:

```
<add name="EcoMembershipProvider" type="Eco.Web.AspProviders.EcoMembershipProvider" EcoSpaceTypeName="Diamonds.DiamondsEcoSpace" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" userNameCaseSensitive="false" applicationName="/Diamonds" />
```

For readability, of course.

Is there any way to stop VS from touching web.config until it really needs to change something?

Or perhaps the rules can be changed to format the way I want for tag lines that are longer than N characters?

I think the same problem applies to app.config, but I haven't checked.

Comment: It doesn't touch my configs in any way, have you installed some other tools?

Comment: Yes, I have [MDriven](http://www.capableobjects.com) (formerly known as ECO). And some NuGet packages. ECO contains extensions to VS. I'm reluctant to try an uninstallation, but I could ask them...

Comment: Come to think of it, I have [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/DPack/) too. CapableObjects (MDriven) claims not to touch web.config at all...

Comment: Any solution to this issue?

Comment: Not really. I suspect it might be NuGet upon package fetch/update/whatnot. Seems to happen on publish but not on build for normal test/debug inside ide.